# Wicked Wizard rolling back on first step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, wizard, wicked-gem

I have started a rails app and setup devise with Group as the model, not user. I'm trying to extend an after registration wizard to update some information about the group. So far I can register, go to the first step after registration, but when I submit the first step of the wizard, it gives this output below. It is odd that it is rolling back, but I"m not sure what is causing that. Here is a gist of several files: https://gist.github.com/DevanB/6828942

I've scraped and restarted several times, but always the same result. Any advice would be helpful! Thanks Stack!

```
Started PUT "/after_register/group_info" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-04 11:42:20 -0500
Processing by AfterRegisterController#update as HTML
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"T1kQN0Nn83/ti86EzAifb5w6ASVKTdD0fLvOIIxHYv0=", "group"=>{"address"=>"1234 Test Street", "city"=>"Timbuktu", "state"=>"AL", "zip"=>"35096", "phone"=>"1 (234) 567-8900", "fax"=>"1 (234) 567-8900"}, "commit"=>"Next", "id"=>"group_info"}
Group Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `groups`.* FROM `groups` WHERE `groups`.`id` = 14 LIMIT 1
 (0.1ms)  BEGIN
 (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
 (0.1ms)  BEGIN
 (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Rendered after_register/group_info.html.erb within layouts/application (7.2ms)
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 49ms (Views: 43.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

Comment: You likely have a rescue block that is swallowing a DB exception.  Can you find it and post the exception trace?

Comment: I haven't written any rescue blocks that I know of. The only "custom" things I have done is overwrite the `after_sign_up_path_for` in the registrations_controller.rb

I'm not sure how to find it and post an exception trace (I'm not sure what an exception trace is actually). I'm somewhat new to Rails. I'll be glad to post more files if necessary.